# Sending a message from cloud backend (Mobile Backend Starter)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Has anyone tried sending a cloud message from the backend of the app configure page?

I tried doing it but `onBroadcastMessageReceived()` is never called in `GuestbookActivity`. I opened up the source in `CloudBackendActivity` and found that the backend subscribes to cloud messages of Topic id `_broadcast` which is the default ID in the backend configure page. The `subscribeToCloudMessaging()` call is definitely called but the handler never seems to call `onComplete()`.

Comment: GCM is definitely enabled as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with `onBroadcastMessageReceived()` in `GuestbookActivity` .
To make it receiving broadcast messages I commented listed below condition in `CloudBackendActivity`.

```
    private void _onPostCreate() {

    //      if (!isSubscribedToBroadcastMessage) {
    //          isSubscribedToBroadcastMessage = true;
        CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>> handler = 
    new CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(List<CloudEntity> results) {
                onBroadcastMessageReceived(results);
            }
        };
        cloudBackend.subscribeToCloudMessage(
                CloudBackendMessaging.TOPIC_ID_BROADCAST, handler);
    //      }

    this.onPostCreate();
}
```

So the issue is in wrong condition.

Comment: I cant find the CloudBackendActivity class in the project dir. I have got the latest code for the Android client, and I believe it is not there. Am I not looking at the right place ?

Comment: Recently Mobile Backend Starter has been updated to Version 2 and CloudBackendActivity is not included there. If you will visit Mobile Backend Starter [GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-android-client) you'll see that it has been upgraded 17 days ago so the listed above answer is only for MBS Version 1